# Woocommerce rest api custom routes not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce-rest-api, wordpress-rest-api

I have registered new custom routes for woocommerce rest api, using below code

```
const Product_Review = 'products/reviews/(?P<product_id>[\d]+)';
public function register_routes( $routes ) {
    $routes[ self::Product_Review ] = array(array(
        array( $this, 'create_product_review_item' ),
        WC_API_Server::EDITABLE | WC_API_Server::CREATABLE | WC_API_Server::ACCEPT_DATA 
    ));
    return $routes;
}
```

this route is successfully registed as i'm able to see it in woocommerce endpoints like this :

[image]

But when i'm calling this api from javascript then it's give me this error:

```
{
    "errors":[
        {
            "code":"woocommerce_api_no_route",
            "message":"No route was found matching the URL and request method"
        }
    ]
}
```

My URL :

```
http://angular.templatic.net/wc-api/v3/products/reviews/31?oauth_consumer_key=ck_9ae878f7a1fa134a2acad1eef7c0182dd3f7e68a&oauth_nonce=d3gf9k8KQXrzGV3LTugcVqrrdME6wzCz&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA256&oauth_timestamp=1481008886&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=xahKi7PjaLxEUaJWPTUnewbI0JoJKYi2Vtn3L2KF1%2FM%3D
```

I want to use this routes for post method for insert data in db.

Comment: Can you show us the full url you are callling from your js? Also are you calling with one of the supported methods the url?

Comment: Done by changing `const Product_Review = '/products/reviews/(?P<product_id>[\d]+)';`